# Map reduce | Grouping on response of map function and show count

Tags: javascript, dictionary, mapreduce, reduce, couchbase-view

the response of my map function is:

key:

```
[ 1525132800000, 1525152600000 ]
```

value:

```
{
  "propertyId": "DAWN",
  "startDate": "2018-05-01",
  "endDate": "2018-05-04",
  "verificationStatusCode": "ICMO"
}
```

In Key, there are two date fields which are used for filtering out the required result set.
I want to get the counts of docs after grouping them on all the fields available in the response of map function. I am not able to write reduce function for this. Any suggestion on how it can be done?
The response from the reduce function I want is:

```
{
  "propertyId": "DAWN",
  "startDate": "2018-05-01",
  "endDate": "2018-05-04",
  "verificationStatusCode": "ICMO", 
 "count":54
}
```

Comment: What are given array(s) and what is the expected output?

Comment: @Eddie, this is the N1QL query that I am trying to convert into map reduce. Hope it helps. 

`Select propertyId, startDate, endDate, verificationStatusCode, Count(*)
From default 
Where type = "DocumentStatus"
and lastModifiedDocDateEPOCH >= 1521718200000
and startDateEpoch between 1522627200000 and 1523232000000
Group by propertyId, startDate, endDate, verificationStatusCode 
;`

Comment: This is the document structure: 

`{
  "propertyId": "DAWN",
  "startDate": "2018-05-01",
  "endDate": "2018-05-04",
  "startDateEpoch":1525132800000,
  "endDateEpoch": 1525392000000, 
  "lastModifiedDocDateEPOCH": 1521718200000, 
  "verificationStatusCode": "ICMO"
}`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a long combination of keys for grouping and filtering, it would look like this:

```
emit([propertyId, startDate, endDate, verificationStatusCode, startDateEpoch, lastModifiedDocDateEPOCH])
```

and the key ranges should look like this

```
query.range(
    [propertyId, startDate, endDate, verificationStatusCode, "1522627200000"], 
    [propertyId, startDate, endDate, verificationStatusCode, "1523232000000", {}])
```